# Alexa Proactive Events API - How to determine if user disabled Alexa notification?

Tags: api, events, notifications, alexa-skills-kit, proactive

In our Alexa skill, we want to determine if a user disabled Alexa Notifications permission. So, we added the following to the skill.json:

```
...
"subscriptions": [
    {
      "eventName": "SKILL_PROACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED"
    }
],
...
```

Then, we created an Intent Handler that would respond to requests of type `AlexaSkillEvent.ProactiveSubscriptionChanged`.

We have verified that this handler gets invoked when a user gives the Alexa Notification permission but does not get invoked when the user disables the Alexa Notification permission.

How can we determine if a user has disabled Alexa Notification in our skill?